# Dúvidas sobre a integração do MySQL com Java

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jdbc

Estou criando um sistema no NetBeans, utilizando a linguagem Java e o banco de dados MySQL. Escrevi o seguinte código para realizar a conexão entre o programa e o banco de dados:

```
public class Conexao
{
private static final String DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/banco_dados",USUARIO="root",SENHA="root";

public static Connection obter()
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        return DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USUARIO,SENHA);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException|SQLException ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Erro ao estabelecer conexão com o MySQL.");
    }
    return null;
}

public static void fechar(Connection c)
{
    try
    {
        if(c!=null)
            c.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Erro ao fechar conexão com o MySQL.");
    }
}

public static void fechar(Connection c, PreparedStatement ps)
{
    fechar(c);
    try
    {
        if(ps!=null)
            ps.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Erro ao fechar conexão com o MySQL.");
    }
}

public static void fechar(Connection c, PreparedStatement ps, ResultSet rs)
{
    fechar(c,ps);
    try
    {
        if(rs!=null)
            rs.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Erro ao fechar conexão com o MySQL.");
    }
}
}
```

Para a classe `Usuario`, criei a classe `UsuarioDAO`. Ainda vou criar métodos para leitura, edição e exclusão.

```
public class UsuarioDAO
{
public static void inserir(Usuario usuario)
{
    Connection c=Conexao.obter();
    PreparedStatement ps=null;
    try
    {
        ps=c.prepareStatement("insert into usuarios(nome,senha) values(?,?)");
        ps.setString(1,usuario.getNome());
        ps.setBytes(2,usuario.getSenha());
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Erro ao inserir dados no MySQL.");
    }
    finally
    {
        Conexao.fechar(c,ps);
    }
}
}
```

Em relação às classes acima, tenho as seguintes dúvidas:

1. É necessário criar a classe `Conexao` e as classes `DAO` manualmente ou existe alguma funcionalidade no NetBeans que possa configurar a conexão do programa com o banco de dados utilizando um formulário ou algo do tipo?
2. É necessário abrir e fechar a conexão sempre que for fazer uma consulta ou alteração no banco de dados? Por quê?
3. É necessário criar três sobrecargas do método `fechar` na classe `Conexao`? Por quê?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1. É necessário criar a classe `Conexao`e as classes `DAO` manualmente ou existe alguma funcionalidade no NetBeans que possa configurar a conexão do programa com o banco de dados utilizando a interface gráfica?

Fazer a interface gráfica conhecer o banco de dados ou vice-versa é uma má prática de programação, pois vai contra o padrão MVC. O motivo é que detalhes do banco de dados são coisas do seu modelo, ou seja, aquilo que modela os dados da sua aplicação e as regras de negócio. Assim sendo, o modelo não deve estar poluído com lógica de exibição/apresentação desses dados. Portanto, aqueles `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` dentro do `DAO` é algo ruim de se fazer.

A base de dados é algo que está na base do modelo, provavelmente em uma camada abaixo da de serviços e regras de negócio e encapsulada nele. Se o modelo expor o acesso ao banco de dados diretamente para a camada de visualização, isso indica uma quebra do encapsulamento, o que implica em uma arquitetura ruim. Assim sendo, a interface gráfica não deveria acessar o seu banco de dados diretamente sem ser por intermédio do modelo.

Entretanto, se você quiser usar alguma geração automática de DAOs no Netbeans, pode dar uma olhada nesse plugin: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/60454/sql-dal-maker (nunca usei, então não sei se é bom).

> 2. É necessário abrir e fechar a conexão sempre que for fazer uma consulta ou alteração no banco de dados? Por que?

Não é realmente necessário, mas controlar isso de forma adequada é algo significativamente trabalhoso. Recomendo você sempre abrir e fechar a conexão por segurança e só pensar em reutilizar conexões quando já for bem experiente em Java, pois é muito fácil fazer besteiras com isso.

> 3. É necessário criar três sobrecargas do método `fechar` na classe `Conexao`? Por que?

Não é necessário. Use a sintaxe *try-with-resources*:

```java
public class UsuarioDAO {

    private static final String INSERIR_SQL = 
            "INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, senha) VALUES (?, ?)";

    public static void inserir(Usuario usuario) {
        try (
            Connection c = Conexao.obter();
            PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(INSERIR_SQL);
        ) {
            ps.setString(1,usuario.getNome());
            ps.setBytes(2,usuario.getSenha());
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // A fazer: Não misturar lógica de apresentação com lógica de banco de dados.
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao inserir dados no MySQL.");
        }
    }
}
```

Com a sintaxe do *try-with-resources*, o compilador insere por conta própria um bloco *finally* que fecha todos os objetos que são abertos no início do *try* (na parte entre os parênteses). A finalidade dessa sintaxe é exatamente a de livrar o programador da necessidade e da complexidade de fechar explicitamente os recursos abertos. Para entender mais, [veja essa minha pergunta e a sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132).

E aqui vai a sua classe `Conexao` revisada:

```java
public class Conexao {
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/banco_dados";
    private static final String USUARIO = "root";
    private static final String SENHA = "root";

    public static Connection obter() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USUARIO, SENHA);
    }
}
```

Na classe `Conexao`, o `Class.forName(DRIVER)` não é mais necessário a partir do Java 6. Entretanto, se quiser preservá-lo por algum motivo, inclua isso na classe também:

```
    private static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static {
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }
```

A inicialização deve ser feito idealmente quando a classe é carregada, e se isso der errado, a aplicação está irremediavelmente quebrada (erro de classpath).

Além disso, o método `obter()` não deve tentar tratar o `SQLException`, e sim relançá-lo para que ele seja tratado em outro lugar. E retornar `null` ali é uma péssima ideia, é pedir para ter um `NullPointerException` depois.

Comment: Legal o uso do try-with-resources, mas tenho uma dúvida. Onde a conexão é fechada nele?

Comment: `Class.forName(DRIVER);` acredito que não seja mais necessário, desde o java6(jdbc 4), se o driver do banco fizer parte do classhpath, ele é localizado automaticamente.http://stackoverflow.com/a/28220844/5524514

Comment: @DiegoAugusto Com a sintaxe do *try-with-resources*, o compilador insere por conta própria um bloco *finally* que fecha todos os objetos que são abertos no início do *try* (na parte entre os parênteses). A finalidade dessa sintaxe é exatamente a de livrar o programador da necessidade e da complexidade de fechar explicitamente os recursos abertos.

Comment: Entendi, bem bacana, não conhecia.

Comment: @diegofm Resposta editada. Obrigado. :)

Comment: @diegofm, Não entendi a resposta para o tópico 1, não sei se é o caso, mas por que a questão da interface gráfica conhecer a base de dados vai de em contra o MVC. Acredito que a questão é em relação a automatização da IDE no preenchimento dos parâmetros da conexão.

Comment: @MarcosSousa Porque a base de dados é algo que está na base do modelo, provavelmente em uma camada abaixo da de serviços e regras de negócio e **encapsulada** nele. Se o modelo expor o acesso ao banco de dados diretamente para a camada de visualização, isso indica uma quebra do encapsulamento, o que implica em uma arquitetura ruim.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, entendi esse conceito(obrigado), porém, não sei se entendi certo, mas pensei que a pergunta se referia ao NetBeans configurar a conexão, algo como criar uma conexão e configura-la com os devidos parâmetros. e foi uma prática que utilizei bastante, porém nunca percebi o problema de encapsulamento. enfim é uma dúvida pessoal.

Comment: Victor, com relação ao 1, eu entendi que ele quer saber se existe algum tipo de ajuda na IDE Netbeans para criar as classes de conexão e DAOs.

Comment: Em relação à 1ª pergunta, eu estava perguntando sobre a existência de alguma funcionalidade (por exemplo, um formulário) que automatize a criação da classe `Conexao` e das classes `DAO` no NetBeans. Eu já editei a pergunta.

Comment: @MarceloHenriqueBittencourt Olhe isso: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/60454/sql-dal-maker

Comment: @RaimundoNorberto Resposta editada.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, obrigado pelos esclarecimentos.

Comment: Outra dúvida: Se o método lançar exceção em vez de pegá-la, o _try-with-resources_ não será mais necessário. Os objetos serão fechados assim mesmo?

Comment: @MarceloHenriqueBittencourt Se o método lançar exceção, ele vai tentar executar o *finally* que o compilador coloca. Isso significa que ele vai também tentar fechar os recursos mesmo se uma exceção for lançada.

Comment: Ok, obrigado mais uma vez.