# Java/Postgresql - Função não retorna valores

Tags: java, web-service, postgresql

Estou criando um webservice onde ira retornar os valores de minha tabela do postgresql. Porem, quando executo esta função, aparece um tela em branco como se não houvesse nenhum dado a ser retornado. Testei errar propositalmente os dados de conexao como driver, user, password, bd e etc. e tbem tentei incluir erros no próprio comando do select, porem quando faço um erro em qualquer desses dados, acaba apresentando um erro diferente. Os códigos abaixo estão com as informações corretas, mas mesmo assim nao apresenta uma mensagem de erro, apenas a tela em branco sem informações.

Creio que pode ser alguma configuração errada no próprio postgresql, porem até ja configurei ele para ter acesso externo nos arquivos pg_hba.conf e postgresql.conf e mesmo assim não houve mudanças.

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host     all     all     127.0.0.1/32    md5
host     all     all     0.0.0.0/0   md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               md5

# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

Função usada=

```
public List<Usuario> listar()
    {
         String sql = "SELECT * FROM Usuario";
        List<Usuario> retorno = new ArrayList<Usuario>();

        PreparedStatement pst = Conexao.getPreparedStatement(sql);
        try {


            ResultSet res = pst.executeQuery();
            while(res.next())
            {
                Usuario item = new Usuario();
                item.setLogin(res.getString("Login"));
                item.setSenha(res.getString("Senha"));
                item.setEmail(res.getString("Email"));
                item.setNome(res.getString("Nome"));

                retorno.add(item);
            }



        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UsuarioDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }

        return retorno;


    }
```

Classe Usuario =

```
public class Usuario {

    private String Login;
    private String Senha;
    private String Email;
    private String Nome;

    public String getLogin() {
        return Login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String Login) {
        this.Login = Login;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return Senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String Senha) {
        this.Senha = Senha;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String Email) {
        this.Email = Email;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return Nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String Nome) {
        this.Nome = Nome;
}

}
```

Classe de Conexao=

```
public class Conexao {

    private static final String banco = 
            "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/OniPresente";
    /**
     * O atributo driver representa a classe do Driver JDBC que será usada na 
     * conexão. Quando se utiliza outros bancos usa-se a classe apropriada a 
     * cada banco
     */
    private static final String driver = 
            "org.postgresql.Driver";
    /**
     * Os atributos usuario e senha representam usuario e senha do 
     * SGBD a ser usado na conexão
     */
    private static final String usuario = "postgres";
    private static final String senha = "1234";  
    /**
     * O atributo con representa um objeto que 
     * contém a conexão com o banco de dados em si
     */
    private static Connection con = null;

    /**
     * Metodo que retorna uma conexão com o banco de dados
     * @return objeto java.sql.Connection
     */
    public static Connection getConexao(){
        // primeiro testo se o objeto con não foi inicializado
        if (con == null){
            try {
                // defino a classe do driver a ser usado
                Class.forName(driver);
                // criação da conexão com o BD
                con = 
                DriverManager.getConnection(
                        banco, usuario, senha);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println("Não encontrou o driver");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println("Erro ao conectar: "+
                        ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return con;
    }
    /**
     * Método que recebe um comando SQL para ser executado
     * @param sql
     * @return um objeto java.sql.PreparedStatement
     */
    public static PreparedStatement getPreparedStatement(String sql){
        // testo se a conexão já foi criada
        if (con == null){
            // cria a conexão
            con = getConexao();
        }
        try {
            // retorna um objeto java.sql.PreparedStatement
            return con.prepareStatement(sql);
        } catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Erro de sql: "+
                    e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
}
```

Banco=

```
CREATE TABLE "Usuario"
(
  "IdUsuario" integer NOT NULL,
  "Login" character varying(20),
  "Senha" character varying(20),
  "Nome" character varying(50),
  "Chave" character varying(20),
  "DtNasc" date,
  "Fone" character varying(11),
  "Email" character varying(30),
  "OAB" character varying(10),
  "Endereco" character varying(50),
  "Bairro" character varying(20),
  "CEP" character varying(10),
  "CodCidade" integer,
  "CPF" character varying(15),
  "CNPJ" character varying(20),
  CONSTRAINT pk_usuario PRIMARY KEY ("IdUsuario")
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE "Usuario" OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Tentou debugar? Verifica se a variavel retorno está sendo populada

Comment: Leia [**esta resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132) e também [**esta outra**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/172816/132) para ter ideias de como melhorar o seu código. Entretanto, essas respostas talvez ainda não deverão ser suficientes para solucionar o seu problema.